# How to call a jsp page from spring secure java class?

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, spring-security

I have a requirement in which i want to call a jsp page of another web app passing parameters to it.But I can't use simple servlet since I have used spring security along with struts interceptors.What I want is just to call a jsp page passing some values to it and then capturing the response from it as true/false.

I have tried this:

```
       try {
            URL url = new URL("http://someURL/page.jsp/");
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String htmlText = "";
            String nextLine = "";
            while ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                htmlText = htmlText + nextLine;
            }
            System.out.println(htmlText);

        } catch (MalformedURLException murle) {
            System.err.println("MalformedURLException: " + murle.getMessage());

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
```

and I am getting response like this :

```
<!doctype html>
    <html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
            <meta itemprop="image" content="/images/google_favicon_128.png">      
            <title>Google</title>
            <script>window.google={kEI:"SwcyT9XhLofUrQe7wsiGBA",getEI:function(a){var d;while(a&&!(a.getAttribute&&(d=a.getAttribute("eid"))))a=a.parentNode;return d||google.kEI},https:function(){return window.location.protocol=="https:"},kEXPI:"34709,35055,36045,36121,36483",kCSI:{e:"34709,35055,36045,36121,36483",ei:"SwcyT9XhLofUrQe7wsiGBA"},authuser:0,ml:function(){},kHL:"en",time:function(){return(new Date).getTime()},log:function(a,d,f,h){var e=new Image,g=google,k=g.lc,i=g.li,m="";e.onerror=(e.onload=(e.onabort=function(){delete k[i]}));k[i]=e;if(!f&&d.search("&ei=")==-1)m="&ei="+google.getEI(h);var j=f||"/gen_204?atyp=i&ct="+a+"&cad="+d+m+"&zx="+google.time(),b=/^http:/i;if(b.test(j)&&google.https()){google.ml(new Error("GLMM"),false,{src:j});delete k[i];return}e.src=j;g.li=i+1},lc:[],li:0,Toolbelt:{},y:{},x:function(a,d){google.y[a.id]=[a,d];return false}};(function(){var a=google.kEI;window.pp_tos={};var d=document.domain.replace(/.*?(google\..*)/,"$1");function f(){var b=0;try{var c=document.cookie.match(/PP_TOS_ACK=([^;]*)/);b=c&&!isNaN(c[1])?c[1]:0}catch(l){e("error","read_cookie")}return b}function h(b){var c=f();if(c>=0){g(++c);if(f()>0&&!b)m()}}function e(b,c){var l=new Image;c=c?"&emsg="+c:"";l.src=["//",d,"/gen_204?atyp=i&ct=pp_tos&cd=",b,"&source=","web","&ei=",a,c].join("");window.pp_tos.beacon=l}function g(b){var c=new Date((new Date).getTime()+5184000000);try{var l="PP_TOS_ACK="+b+"; expires="+c.toGMTString()+"; path=/; domain="+d;document.cookie=l}catch(n){e("error","write_cookie")}}function k(){g(-1);e("dismiss");j()}function i(){g(-1);e("tellmore");j()}function m(){var b=document.getElementById("bb_pp_tos_ack");if(b){b.style.display="";e("display")}}function j(){var b=document.getElementById("bb_pp_tos_ack");if(b)b.style.display="none"}window.pp_tos.handleDismiss=k;window.pp_tos.handleLearnMore=i;window.pp_tos.checkCookie=h})();window.google.sn="webhp";window.google.timers={};window.google.startTick=function(a,b){window.google.timers[a]={t:{start:(new Date).getTime()},bfr:!(!b)}};window.google.tick=function(a,b,c){if(!window.google.timers[a])google.startTick(a);window.google.timers[a].t[b]=c||(new Date).getTime()};google.startTick("load",true);try{}catch(u){}var _gjwl=location;function _gjuc(){var e=_gjwl.href.indexOf("#");if(e>=0){var a=_gjwl.href.substring(e);if(a.indexOf("&q=")>0||a.indexOf("#q=")>=0){a=a.substring(1);if(a.indexOf("#")==-1){for(var c=0;c<a.length;){var d=c;if(a.charAt(d)=="&")++d;var b=a.indexOf("&",d);if(b==-1)b=a.length;var f=a.substring(d,b);if(f.indexOf("fp=")==0){a=a.substring(0,c)+a.substring(b,a.length);b=c}else if(f=="cad=h")return 0;c=b}_gjwl.href="/search?"+a+"&cad=h";return 1}}}return 0}function _gjp(){!(window._gjwl.hash&&window._gjuc())&&setTimeout(_gjp,500)};window._gjp && _gjp()</script>
            <style>#gbar,#guser{font-size:13px;padding-top:1px !important;}#gbar{height:22px}#guser{padding-bottom:7px !important;text-align:right}.gbh,.gbd{border-top:1px solid #c9d7f1;font-size:1px}.gbh{height:0;position:absolute;top:24px;width:100%}@media all{.gb1{height:22px;margin-right:.5em;vertical-align:top}#gbar{float:left}}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline !important}a.gb1,a.gb4{color:#00c !important}</style>
            <style id=gstyle>body{margin:0;overflow-y:scroll}#gog{padding:3px 8px 0}td{line-height:.8em}.gac_m td{line-height:17px}form{margin-bottom:20px}body,td,a,p,.h{font-family:arial,sans-serif}.h{color:#36c;font-size:20px}.q{color:#00c}.ts td{padding:0}.ts{border-collapse:collapse}em{font-weight:bold;font-style:normal}.lst{height:25px;width:496px}.gsfi,.lst{font:18px arial,sans-serif}.gsfs{font:17px arial,sans-serif}.ds{border-bottom:solid 1px #e7e7e7;border-right:solid 1px #e7e7e7;display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block;margin:3px 0 4px;margin-left:4px}input{font-family:inherit}a.gb1,a.gb2,a.gb3,a.gb4{color:#11c !important}body{background:#fff;color:black}a{color:#11c;text-decoration:none}a:hover,a:active{text-decoration:underline}.fl a{color:#36c}a:visited{color:#551a8b}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline}a.gb3:hover{text-decoration:none}#ghead a.gb2:hover{color:#fff!important}.sblc{padding-top:5px}.sblc a{display:block;margin:2px 0;margin-left:13px;font-size:11px;}.lsbb{background:#eee;border:solid 1px;border-color:#ccc #999 #999 #ccc;height:30px;display:block}.pp-new-desktop,.pp-new-mobile{color:red}.ftl,#fll a{display:inline-block;margin:0 12px}.lsb{background:url(/images/srpr/nav_logo80.png) 0 -258px repeat-x;border:none;color:#000;cursor:pointer;height:30px;margin:0;outline:0;font:15px arial,sans-serif;vertical-align:top}.lsb:active{background:#ccc}.lst:focus{outline:none}#addlang a{padding:0 3px}.gac_v div{display:none}.gac_v .gac_v2,.gac_bt{display:block!important}table.gssb_c{z-index:986  }.nbcl{background:url(/images/srpr/nav_logo80.png) no-repeat ;height:px;width:px}</style>
            <script>window.rwt=function(a,f,g,l,m,h,c,n,i){try{if(a===window){a=window.event.srcElement;while(a){if(a.href)break;a=a.parentNode}}var b=encodeURIComponent||escape,d;d=a.getAttribute("href");if(c&&c.substring(0,6)!="&sig2=")c="&sig2="+c;var o=["/url?sa=t","","&cd=",b(m),i?"&authuser="+b(i):"",google.j&&google.j.pf?"&sqi=2":"","&ved=",b(n),"&url=",b(d).replace(/\+/g,"%2B"),"&ei=","SwcyT9XhLofUrQe7wsiGBA",h?"&usg="+h:"",c].join("");a.href=o;a.onmousedown=""}catch(p){}return true};</script>
        </head>
        <body bgcolor=#ffffff text=#000000 link=#0000cc vlink=#551a8b alink=#ff0000 onload="document.f&&document.f.q.focus();document.gbqf&&document.gbqf.q.focus();if(document.images)new Image().src='/images/srpr/nav_logo80.png'" >
            <textarea id=csi style=display:none></textarea>
            <div id=mngb>
                <div id=gbar>
                    <nobr>
                        <b class=gb1>Search</b> 
                        <a class=gb1 href="http://www.google.co.in/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi">Images</a> 
                        <a class=gb1 href="http://maps.google.co.in/maps?hl=en&tab=wl">Maps</a> 
                        <a class=gb1 href="http://news.google.co.in/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn">News</a> 
                        <a class=gb1 href="http://www.orkut.com/Main?tab=w0#Home">Orkut</a> 
                        <a class=gb1 href="http://translate.google.co.in/?hl=en&tab=wT">Translate</a> 
                        <a class=gb1 href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm">Gmail</a> 
                        <a class=gb1 style="text-decoration:none" href="http://www.google.co.in/intl/en/options/"><u>More</u> &raquo;</a>
                    </nobr>
                </div>
                <div id=guser width=100%>
                    <nobr>
                        <span id=gbn class=gbi></span>
                        <span id=gbf class=gbf></span>
                        <span id=gbe>
                            <a  href="/url?sa=p&pref=ig&pval=3&q=http://www.google.co.in/ig%3Fhl%3Den%26source%3Diglk&usg=AFQjCNHe9Dv_h1zYL1VKlS7wKo_0Kg38dg" class=gb4>iGoogle</a> | 
                        </span>
                        <a href="http://www.google.com/history/optout?hl=en" class=gb4>Web History</a> | 
                        <a  href="/preferences?hl=en" class=gb4>Settings</a> | <a id=gb_70 href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&continue=http://www.google.co.in/" class=gb4>Sign in</a>
                    </nobr>
                </div>
                <div class=gbh style=left:0></div>
                <div class=gbh style=right:0></div>
            </div>
            <center>
                <br clear=all id=lgpd>
                <div id=lga>
                    <div style="padding:28px 0 3px">
                        <div align=left style="background:url(/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png) no-repeat;height:110px;width:276px" title="Google" id=hplogo onload="window.lol&&lol()">
                            <div nowrap style="color:#777;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;left:214px;position:relative;top:70px">India</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <form action="/search" name=f>
                    <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
                        <tr valign=top>
                            <td width=25%>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align=center nowrap>
                                <input name=hl type=hidden value=en>
                                <input name=source type=hidden value=hp>
                                <input type=hidden name=ie value="ISO-8859-1">
                                <div class=ds style="height:32px;margin:4px 0">
                                    <input autocomplete=off maxlength=2048 name=q class="lst" title="Google Search" value="" size=57 style="background:#fff;border:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom-color:#999;border-right-color:#999;color:#000;margin:0;padding:5px 8px 0 6px;vertical-align:top">
                                </div>
                                <br style="line-height:0">
                                <span class=ds >
                                    <span class=lsbb>
                                        <input name=btnG type=submit value="Google Search" class=lsb>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                                <span class=ds>
                                    <span class=lsbb>
                                        <input name=btnI type=submit class=lsb value="I&#39;m Feeling Lucky">
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap width=25% align=left class="fl sblc">
                                <a href="/advanced_search?hl=en">Advanced search</a>
                                <a href="/language_tools?hl=en">Language tools</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <input type=hidden id=gbv name=gbv value="1">
                </form><div style="font-size:83%;min-height:3.5em">
                <br>
                <div id=als>
                    <font size=-1 id=addlang>Google.co.in offered in: 
                        <a href="http://www.google.co.in/setprefs?sig=0_DDnMKGiVFxFvNLf08409BXmS8WU=&amp;hl=hi">Hindi</a> 
                        <a href="http://www.google.co.in/setprefs?sig=0_DDnMKGiVFxFvNLf08409BXmS8WU=&amp;hl=bn">Bengali</a> 
                        <a href="http://www.google.co.in/setprefs?sig=0_DDnMKGiVFxFvNLf08409BXmS8WU=&amp;hl=te">Telugu</a> 
                        <a href="http://www.google.co.in/setprefs?sig=0_DDnMKGiVFxFvNLf08409BXmS8WU=&amp;hl=mr">Marathi</a> 
                        <a href="http://www.google.co.in/setprefs?sig=0_DDnMKGiVFxFvNLf08409BXmS8WU=&amp;hl=ta">Tamil</a> 
                        <a href="http://www.google.co.in/setprefs?sig=0_DDnMKGiVFxFvNLf08409BXmS8WU=&amp;hl=gu">Gujarati</a> 
                        <a href="http://www.google.co.in/setprefs?sig=0_DDnMKGiVFxFvNLf08409BXmS8WU=&amp;hl=kn">Kannada</a> 
                        <a href="http://www.google.co.in/setprefs?sig=0_DDnMKGiVFxFvNLf08409BXmS8WU=&amp;hl=ml">Malayalam</a> 
                        <a href="http://www.google.co.in/setprefs?sig=0_DDnMKGiVFxFvNLf08409BXmS8WU=&amp;hl=pa">Punjabi</a>
                    </font>
                    <br><br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id=res></div>
            <span id=footer>
                <center id=fctr>
                    <div style="font-size:10pt">
                        <div id=fll style="margin:19px auto;text-align:center">
                            <a href="/intl/en/ads/">Advertising&nbsp;Programs</a>
                            <a href="http://www.google.co.in/services/">Business Solutions</a>
                            <a href="/intl/en/about.html">About Google</a>
                            <a href="http://www.google.com/ncr" class="gl nobr">Go to Google.com</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p style="color:#767676;font-size:8pt">
                        &copy; 2012 - <a href="/intl/en/privacy.html">Privacy</a>
                    </p>
                </center>
            </span> 
            <div id=xjsd></div>
            <div id=xjsi>
                <script>if(google.y)google.y.first=[];google.dlj=function(b){window.setTimeout(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");a.src=b;document.getElementById("xjsd").appendChild(a)},0)};if(google.y)google.y.first=[];if(!google.xjs){google.dstr=[];google.rein=[];if(google.timers&&google.timers.load.t){google.timers.load.t.xjsls=new Date().getTime();}google.dlj('/extern_js/f/CgJlbhICaW4gACswRTgALCswWjgALCswDjgALCswFzgALCswPDgALCswUTgALCswCjgAmgICaGUsKzCYATgALCswFjgALCswGTgALCswQTgALCswTTgALCswTjgALCswVDgALCswaTgALCswkAE4ACwrMJIBOAAsKzDYATgALCswGDgALCswJjgALIACUJACYw/bbNmQ_tfM2A.js');google.xjs=1}google.neegg=1;google.mc=[];google.mc=google.mc.concat([[69,{}],[14,{}],[60,{}],[23,{}],[81,{}],[10,{"client":"hp","dh":true,"ds":"","fl":true,"host":"google.co.in","jsonp":true,"msgs":{"lcky":"I\u0026#39;m Feeling Lucky","lml":"Learn more","psrc":"This search was removed from your \u003Ca href=\"/history\"\u003EWeb History\u003C/a\u003E","psrl":"Remove","srch":"Google Search"},"ovr":{"o":1,"pf":1,"ps":1,"sn":1,"sw":1},"pq":"","scd":10,"sce":5}],[152,{}],[65,{}],[78,{}],[25,{"g":8,"k":false,"m":{"app":true,"bks":true,"blg":true,"dsc":true,"evn":true,"flm":true,"frm":true,"isch":true,"klg":true,"mbl":true,"nws":true,"plcs":true,"ppl":true,"prc":true,"pts":true,"rcp":true,"shop":true,"vid":true},"t":null}],[216,{}],[105,{}],[22,{"db":false,"m_errors":{"32":"Sorry, no more results to show.","default":"\u003Cfont color=red\u003EError:\u003C/font\u003E The server could not complete your request.  Try again in 30 seconds."},"m_tip":"Click for more information","nlpm":"-153px -84px","nlpp":"-153px -70px","utp":false}],[77,{}],[146,{}],[144,{}],[84,{}],[24,{}],[38,{}]]);google.y.first.push(function(){if(google.med){google.med('init');google.initHistory();google.med('history');}google.History&&google.History.initialize('/')});if(google.j&&google.j.en&&google.j.xi){window.setTimeout(google.j.xi,0);}</script></div><script>(function(){var b,d,e,f;function g(a,c){if(a.removeEventListener){a.removeEventListener("load",c,false);a.removeEventListener("error",c,false)}else{a.detachEvent("onload",c);a.detachEvent("onerror",c)}}function h(a){f=(new Date).getTime();++d;a=a||window.event;var c=a.target||a.srcElement;g(c,h)}var i=document.getElementsByTagName("img");b=i.length;d=0;for(var j=0,k;j<b;++j){k=i[j];if(k.complete||typeof k.src!="string"||!k.src)++d;else if(k.addEventListener){k.addEventListener("load",h,false);k.addEventListener("error",h,false)}else{k.attachEvent("onload",h);k.attachEvent("onerror",h)}}e=b-d;function l(){if(!google.timers.load.t)return;google.timers.load.t.ol=(new Date).getTime();google.timers.load.t.iml=f;google.kCSI.imc=d;google.kCSI.imn=b;google.kCSI.imp=e;if(google.stt!==undefined)google.kCSI.stt=google.stt;google.timers.load.t.xjs&&google.report&&google.report(google.timers.load,google.kCSI)}if(window.addEventListener)window.addEventListener("load",l,false);else if(window.attachEvent)window.attachEvent("onload",l);google.timers.load.t.prt=(f=(new Date).getTime());})();</script>
```

The class in which I have written this code is implementing authenticationManager of spring security i.e after login directly this class is being called as per the xml configuration.

Now my question is : in the response of the URL passed, I will get one field saying true/false.How can I capture that field in my response ??

Or is there any better way (excluding servlets/jsps) which I can use along with spring security context ??

Comment: it's very hard to read that large response, on one line

Comment: I don't fully understand. Are you asking how to disable spring security for the JSP you are trying to call, or are you asking how to authenticate against Spring security from your other web app?

Comment: instead of response html posting an image would probably be better

Comment: "I will get one field saying true/false" - where is this field in the HTML you have posted?